# rescue in block in dlload': can't load user32 (Fiddle::DLError) on running cap

Tags: ruby, ssh, rubygems, capistrano

I installed Capistrano 2 and am facing problems white executing the cap
command.  The OS is Windows 2012 R2.
So when I run, 
cap <<>> deploy,

the error displayed is,

> /usr/share/ruby/2.3.0/fiddle/import.rb:86:in `rescue in block in
>   dlload': can't load user32 (Fiddle::DLError)

```
from /usr/share/ruby/2.3.0/fiddle/import.rb:83:in `block in dlload'
    from /usr/share/ruby/2.3.0/fiddle/import.rb:74:in `collect'
    from /usr/share/ruby/2.3.0/fiddle/import.rb:74:in `dlload'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:59:in
    `<module:Win>'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:41:in
    `<module:Pageant>'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:33:in
    `<module:Authentication>'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:24:in
    `<module:SSH>'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:24:in
    `<module:Net>'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:9:in
    `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in`<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in`<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-4.0.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:12:in`<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-gateway-2.0.0/lib/net/ssh/gateway.rb:2:in`<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-2.15.9/lib/capistrano/configuration/connections.rb:2:in`<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-2.15.9/lib/capistrano/configuration.rb:5:in`<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-2.15./lib/capistrano.rb:3:in`<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-2.15./lib/capistrano/cli.rb:1:in`<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ex/kernel_require.rb:55:in
    `require'
    from /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/capistrano-2.15.9/bin/cap:3:in
    `<top (required)>'
    from /home/Administrator/bin/cap:23:in `load'
    from /home/Administrator/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'

My gem environment info is given below -

RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.12
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.3 (2016-11-21 patchlevel 222) [x86_64-cygwin]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/Administrator/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/Administrator/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-cygwin
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/Administrator/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /usr/share/gems
     - /usr/local/share/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
```

And the gem list is  -

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

builder (3.2.2)
capistrano (2.15.9)
capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
capistrano_rsync_with_remote_cache (2.4.0)
did_you_mean (1.0.2)
highline (1.7.8)
io-console (0.4.6)
json (1.8.6)
minitest (5.10.1)
net-scp (1.2.1)
net-sftp (2.1.2)
net-ssh (4.0.1)
net-ssh-gateway (2.0.0)
psych (2.2.4)
railsless-deploy (1.1.2)
rake (11.3.0)
rdoc (4.3.0)

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but I stumbled in here when trying to find a solution to my problem. It was the same error log shown in the question. It seems to be a general problem with old ruby at least under Windows.

I'm running `Cygwin under Windows 7 x64, with RVM and Ruby 2.2.6`, yes I know it's old.

I had similar problems when installing Ruby with RVM but I solved it temporarily then, and I thought it was only when making the rubies. But now I got the same problem when doing `bundle exec cap some_env deploy`, `capistrano` is using `net-ssh` and there I got the same error as in the question.

The problem is that `Fiddle#dlopen` isn't trying with the extension `.dll`. In the current call with `Fiddle.dlopen("user32")` that causes the error it should have tried with `Fiddle.dlopen("user32.dll")`.

I did a hack that solved it, in `ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fiddle/import.rb` around line 83:

```
      begin
        Fiddle.dlopen(lib)
      rescue DLError
        raise(DLError, "can't load #{lib}")
      end
```

I changed that to

```
      begin
        Fiddle.dlopen(lib)
      rescue DLError
        if lib.to_s !~ /\.dll/
          lib = "#{lib}.dll"
          retry
        end
        raise(DLError, "can't load #{lib}")
      end
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gem files which has the Backward compatibility with 32-bit Ruby.

You are getting the error due that gem. Check the alternative for the same

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30910099)